# In Windows 10 why won't the built in keyboard appear for a Visual Basic InputBox?

Tags: windows-10, on-screen-keyboard, .net-3.5

I've installed a 32-bit  desktop application onto Windows 10 Pro x64 for the first time.  Previously it has been used succesfully on Windows 7.

It is a PC with an external touchscreen monitor used in a Kiosk mode so that the only thing available to the user is the program itself. With out a physical keyboard or closing the program they cannot see the task bar or the system tray.

Under Settings/Devices/Typing I have selected the "Show the touch keyboard or handwriting panel when not in tablet mode and there's no keyboard attached."

The application only has a couple of places that allow the user to type. The keyboard appears nicely at the Windows login and for screens that use a TextBox. But there are a couple of places that use a generic InputBox dialog and the keyboard does not appear.

I've tried the "Add the standard keyboard layout as a touch keyboard option" which didn't seem to have an effect.

Setting OSK to autostart, which is what I used to do in Windows 7, is awkward at best because you can't minimize it without losing it to the hidden system tray and it is oversized compared to the other keyboard.

Is there another setting I need to examine to make it work?

**Update:** The reason the TextBox opens the keyboard is that it is assigned a password character. A normal TextBox does not bring the the keyboard forward either.

Comment: I think the "Show the touch keyboard..." option makes the keyboard icon appear in the system tray, so if it's hidden, that won't make any difference. Hard to tell from your post, but if you have access to the source code, you could write put in event handler that launches the touch screen executable every time an inputbox is clicked. I've done this as a workaround before.

Comment: run the device in tablet mode all the time, here the keyboard should always show up

Comment: @magicandre1981 Same experience in tablet mode.

Comment: @BrianC I do have access, but I was trying to avoid changing the source.  I don't think I have choice though.

Comment: can you provide (github) a small demo app (2 inputs, 1 were OSK is shown and 1 were it is not) were you see the issue?

Comment: @magicandre1981 it looks like the answer will be it can't be done.  See my edit in the OP. I'll have to examine exposing the system tray to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the program and doing further research I can summarize where the keyboard automatically appears with a WinForm program.

- `TextBox` with the `PasswordChar` property set.
- A `ComboBox` with the `DropSownStyle` property set to `DropDown`.

I found that there was no way to get the `InputBox` to use the touch. I ended up making a custom form with a TextBox and attached some custom routines to the Enter and Leave events of the `TextBox`.

Since this isn't the programing site I'll keep it short.

I used the `TabletDeviceCollection` to see if the computer had a `TabletDevice` with a `Type` of `TabletDeviceType.Touch`.

If it did I then launched the keyboard like this:

```
Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe")
```

Then to close it I called the unmanaged `Win32` function  `FindWindow("IPTIP_Main_Window", "")` to get a handle and then called another WIn32 to send it a message. `SendMessage(handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0)`

For more information search on those phrases.